# Secure Inter-Process Communication for sharing Sensitive Information

Tags: c#, .net, security, ipc, named-pipes

I have a scenario where a C#.NET program must be supplied a secret that is derived from a Username/Password combination. This secret is non-reversible (think of it like a hash) but has the requirement that the secret can only be created with a .NET library.

The problem here is that there is the program that actually contains the username/password is different than the program that needs the secret and is not a .NET program, so the information has to be sent through some IPC.

It is worth noting that the program the has the username/password keeps them in memory for as long as the user is logged in. I realize that this itself is very insecure, but it isn't something that I am able to change.

I am looking for a way for the C#.NET program to get the secret as securely as possible.

Two options that I came up with are to use a Named Pipe to transfer the username/password directly from one application to the other, or to use COM components so the first application can send the username/password to the COM component, which can compute the secret and write it to a location that can be read later by the second application.

for the Named Pipe method I would expect the credential requesting component to look something like the following

```
using (var a = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation))
{
    var requestString = new StreamString(a);
    var credString = new StreamString(a);

    await a.ConnectAsync();

    a.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;

    requestString.WriteString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CredentialRequest()));

    var cred = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Credential>(credString.ReadString());

    var secret = await CreateSecret(cred.Username, cred.Password);
    a.Close();
}
```

Based on that, the side opposite side of the pipe should be pretty obvious.

For the COM solution I am thinking that I would create an object that has the following method

```
public void ComputeAndStoreSecret(string username, string password)
    {

        var secret = CreateSecret(username, password);

        using (var applicationStorageFileForUser = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
        {
            using (var applicationStorageStreamForUser = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("secret_store.txt", FileMode.Create, applicationStorageFileForUser))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(applicationStorageStreamForUser))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(secret);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

There would also be a COM component that reads from that storage location and returns the secret.

I am basically looking for any insight as to why I would want to use one of these techniques over the other or maybe consider any other options (RPC, Mailbox, etc.)

Some things that I have discovered/considered

- Named Pipe solution is vulnerable to Pipe Squatting
- Named Pipes require username/password to leave process space of the first application
- Storage Location of secret using COM solution can be seen and edited by everything
- Isolated File Storage in COM solution is [not intended to be used for secret information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage#scenarios_for_isolated_storage)

I realize that neither of these solutions are secure, but I am looking for a solution that at least doesn't make it drastically more insecure.

Comment: If you can't update the program that has the secret, how are you planning to get it to start sending through the IPC you end up choosing?

Comment: I can change that program or rather, I can get someone else to do it, I just can't change the fact that it has to keep the username/password in memory.

Comment: Have you considered using a database as the IPC? Most modern RDBMs allow you to have data encrypted (certificate based) in transit and at rest.

Comment: Regardless of the IPC (named pipe, socket, queue, etc.), is it an option to use asymetric encryption/decryption for this task? You could generate a key pairon the other app (on the fly) and send the public key to the .NET app (which will gather user credentials), and them use the public key to encrypt the user credentials -- the private key remains on the other process memory -- but for each interaction a new key pair could be generated, increasing security